# Bootstrap responsive navigation button not triggering navigation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar, nav

I'm creating a Bootstrap site with Bootstrap navigation. I was following a tutorial, and I did everything that the tutorial told me to do, but my responsive navigation button isn't triggering my navigation to appear. I'm using Bootstrap version 3.0.3 and JQuery 2.0.3 (I have to for a class). I'm not doing anything yet to style my navigation in addition to Bootstrap's own styling.

This is my code for the navigation:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Base Competition Site</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="nav-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse nav-collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="about/about.html"><span>About</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Data</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Login</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My full code is on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leoalfredmusic/5C42b/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the . in the data-target :)

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
```

[updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aibrean/5C42b/2/)

Comment: Thanks! I guess I have to be more careful when writing my code!

Comment: Took me a bit to catch it. Usually I use ID's for that so it's more obvious.